# Juniper SRX550 vpn question

Tags: vpn, srx

First of all, I don't know much about VPNs, so please be patient.

I have a `Juniper SRX550`, and I want users from home to be able to connect to the company network via VPN.

The company I work for has only one location, so I'm assuming I need to setup a remote access vpn? I believe site-to-site is to connect between more than one location.

What information do I need to be able to do this?

Comment: You need to configure Dynamic remote access VPN. You also should know that RA VPN requires license. Avalilable amount of licenses could be seen issuing command `> show system license`.

Comment: Thank you.  I think by default SRX550 comes with 2 licenses, I'll check.

Comment: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos12.1x47/topics/example/vpn-security-dynamic-example-configuring.html                                                                I think this is a good reference for me to start.

Comment: I think the Juniper SRX550 uses Pulse Secure Client

Comment: Also check [this one](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/security-dynamic-vpns-with-pulse-secure-clients.html)

Comment: @MattDamoz According to my Juniper account reps, Juniper no longer partners with Pulse Secure for client VPN and now pushes all new sales to use the NCP client.